# mobileconfig file with mdm payload, is invalid profile

Tags: mdm, payload

I'm trying to install .mobileconfig file that was created through IPCU.
but when I click on an  attached .mobileconfig file in mail. 
It occured error message as "invalid profile".

what is problem ?

if the certificate is problem, please let us know how to make.

Below is the procedure I created the certificate.

1. in keychain, After navigate Keychain Access/Certifiate Assistant/Certificate generate,
   I have generated Certificate. and exported .p12 file
2. .p12 file is used to Credentials setting in IPCU

Answer (score 1):

You could be having any number of problems, but the one I've seen most often is that you're trying to install an encrypted profile and the device can't find the appropriate private key (which must be on the device prior to receiving the profile, and is required for decryption).

Your best bet is to get more information on the problem, which you can do by connecting the device to your Mac or PC, selecting its entry in iPCU (in the left-hand column—the entry that only shows-up once you connect the device) and clicking on the Console tab. This will give you access to the device's system log file, which generally contains a lot more info on what the real issue is.

The process you used to create the certificate seems reasonable enough and isn't likely the reason you're getting the error; I couldn't say much more than that without knowing what you're using the certificate for.

Answer (score 0):

Did you sign the mobileconfig file? If yes, have you tried not to sign it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error message pops up if you are trying to download iOS from macOS. So tap that same link from an iPad instead of on macOS, or choose the iTunes-based download method (iOS Restore Images), and upgrade from iTunes.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/234381#234381