# iOS: How to install a configuration profile programmatically

Tags: ios, configuration, safari, xcode5, profile

I would like to install a configuration profile in an iPhone that I receive through Safari from my localhost (RoutingHTTPServer) in the device.

I follow guidelines and tips that I found in this website to make it possible, but I am facing a small issue, in the final steps. I am able to run the localhost and create the configuration profile, but then Safari does not allow me to install the file due to an "unknown error".

I made some research and I found several possibilities to this "unknown error", most of them related to the format of the contents of the file created. I arrange that in different ways, but still the same problem.

My application it is just a concept solution, but I would like to know if the error could be because, it is mandatory to sign and encrypt the configuration file before sending it through Safari.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to add more information to your question before it can be answered. Please add links to the "guidelines and tips" you followed. How are you creating the configuration profile; how are you installing the profile on the device? Can you add the configuration profile (obfuscate anything confidential!) to the question? Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600849/mobileconfig-file-with-mdm-payload-is-invalid-profile) might help. To be clear: you can't install a configuration profile from a native iOS app.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found the error, it was some missing tags in the file, and now it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not mandatory to sign the configuration profile. Try the following steps

1. Connect the device to the laptop (windows/mac).
2. Open iPhone Configuration Utility.
3. Create a profile of your need.
4. Try installing it into the mobile.
5. Check the console for error.
6. If installation succeeded then export the profile and place it into the web-server and try installing the profile OTA. (Note: Uninstall the previously installed profile).
7. Open the profile and analyse it for identifying your mistake.

Your research is right, the main reason for Unknown Error is the formatting mistake. The detailed description about the payloads and keys are available under [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Finally, it was a formatting mistake in the file, missing some tags. It is already fixed now and running.

Comment: @Anand  hey i m facing the same problem , mobileconfig file work properly when sending by mail, but it is showing Unknown error  or invalid profile when trying to open from  web server. Can you please help me to solve out this puzzle...